# Selecting data from multiple rows in grouped results

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have come across a TSQL problem where I have some grouped results and need some data from each of the rows that make up the grouped results, ideally - I would like the Recipient from the first row as 'HuntGroup and the Recipient from the second row as 'Recipient'.

There may be 1 or 2 rows in the grouped results so I will only need results from where there are 2 rows. There is a CorrelationCode that ties the two records together - one row will have the hunt group info and the other will have the answering user.

If you want to test, you can generate the data from the below:

```
CREATE TABLE #phone_calls
(
    Caller VARCHAR(200),
    Recipient VARCHAR(200),
    CorrelationCode VARCHAR(200),
    StartTime VARCHAR(200),
    EndTime VARCHAR(200),
);

INSERT INTO #phone_calls(Caller, Recipient, CorrelationCode, StartTime, EndTime)
VALUES 
    ( 'user159', 'huntgroup1',  'AEF4562JJH',   DATEADD(mi, -60,GETDATE()), DATEADD(mi, -60, GETDATE()) ),
    ( 'user159', 'user10',      'AEF4562JJH',   DATEADD(mi, -59,GETDATE()), DATEADD(mi, -56, GETDATE()) ),
    ( 'user11', 'huntgroup2',   'OSJEJDJE883',  DATEADD(mi, -58,GETDATE()), DATEADD(mi, -58, GETDATE()) ),
    ( 'user11', 'user5',        'OSJEJDJE883',  DATEADD(mi, -57,GETDATE()), DATEADD(mi, -56, GETDATE()) ),
    ( 'user449', 'huntgroup1',  'SHEJJSMM27',   DATEADD(mi, -56,GETDATE()), DATEADD(mi, -56, GETDATE()) ),
    ( 'user449', 'user91',      'SHEJJSMM27',   DATEADD(mi, -55,GETDATE()), DATEADD(mi, -54, GETDATE()) ),
    ( 'user128', 'huntgroup1',  'USJEHHS45461', DATEADD(mi, -54,GETDATE()), DATEADD(mi, -54, GETDATE()) ),
    ( 'user128', 'user46',      'USJEHHS45461', DATEADD(mi, -53,GETDATE()), DATEADD(mi, -46, GETDATE()) ),
    ( 'user120', 'huntgroup1',  'SEES45646',    DATEADD(mi, -52,GETDATE()), DATEADD(mi, -52, GETDATE()) ),
    ( 'user120', 'user5',       'SEES45646',    DATEADD(mi, -51,GETDATE()), DATEADD(mi, -49, GETDATE()) ),
    ( 'user316', 'huntgroup1',  'LLLS45646',    DATEADD(mi, -50,GETDATE()), DATEADD(mi, -50, GETDATE()) ),
    ( 'user316', 'user5',       'LLLS45646',    DATEADD(mi, -49,GETDATE()), DATEADD(mi, -49, GETDATE()) ),
    ( 'user19', 'huntgroup1',   'YHJASA434',    DATEADD(mi, -48,GETDATE()), DATEADD(mi, -48, GETDATE()) ),
    ( 'user202', 'huntgroup1',  '78RTGDHDG',    DATEADD(mi, -47,GETDATE()), DATEADD(mi, -47, GETDATE()) ),
    ( 'user141', 'huntgroup2',  'CFGBN1231',    DATEADD(mi, -46,GETDATE()), DATEADD(mi, -46, GETDATE()) ),
    ( 'user168', 'huntgroup1',  'KKLDJ5463',    DATEADD(mi, -45,GETDATE()), DATEADD(mi, -45, GETDATE()) ),
    ( 'user168', 'user91',      'KKLDJ5463',    DATEADD(mi, -44,GETDATE()), DATEADD(mi, -40, GETDATE()) );
```

A SELECT * will give the following results:

```
Caller      Recipient   CorrelationCode StartTime       EndTime
user159     huntgroup1  AEF4562JJH  Sep 13 2018  3:56PM Sep 13 2018  3:56PM
user159     user10      AEF4562JJH  Sep 13 2018  3:57PM Sep 13 2018  4:00PM
user11      huntgroup2  OSJEJDJE883 Sep 13 2018  3:58PM Sep 13 2018  3:58PM
user11      user5       OSJEJDJE883 Sep 13 2018  3:59PM Sep 13 2018  4:00PM
user449     huntgroup1  SHEJJSMM27  Sep 13 2018  4:00PM Sep 13 2018  4:00PM
user449     user91      SHEJJSMM27  Sep 13 2018  4:01PM Sep 13 2018  4:02PM
user128     huntgroup1  USJEHHS45461    Sep 13 2018  4:02PM Sep 13 2018  4:02PM
user128     user46      USJEHHS45461    Sep 13 2018  4:03PM Sep 13 2018  4:10PM
user120     huntgroup1  SEES45646   Sep 13 2018  4:04PM Sep 13 2018  4:04PM
user120     user5       SEES45646   Sep 13 2018  4:05PM Sep 13 2018  4:07PM
user316     huntgroup1  LLLS45646   Sep 13 2018  4:06PM Sep 13 2018  4:06PM
user316     user5       LLLS45646   Sep 13 2018  4:07PM Sep 13 2018  4:07PM
user19      huntgroup1  YHJASA434   Sep 13 2018  4:08PM Sep 13 2018  4:08PM
user202     huntgroup1  78RTGDHDG   Sep 13 2018  4:09PM Sep 13 2018  4:09PM
user141     huntgroup2  CFGBN1231   Sep 13 2018  4:10PM Sep 13 2018  4:10PM
user168     huntgroup1  KKLDJ5463   Sep 13 2018  4:11PM Sep 13 2018  4:11PM
user168     user91      KKLDJ5463   Sep 13 2018  4:12PM Sep 13 2018  4:16PM
```

What I am trying to get in the result set is:

```
Caller      HuntGroup   Recipient   CorrelationCode StartTime       EndTime
user159     huntgroup1  user10      AEF4562JJH  Sep 13 2018  3:56PM Sep 13 2018  4:00PM
user168     huntgroup1  user91      KKLDJ5463   Sep 13 2018  4:11PM Sep 13 2018  4:16PM
user316     huntgroup1  user5       LLLS45646   Sep 13 2018  4:06PM Sep 13 2018  4:07PM
user11      huntgroup2  user5       OSJEJDJE883 Sep 13 2018  3:58PM Sep 13 2018  4:00PM
user120     huntgroup1  user5       SEES45646   Sep 13 2018  4:04PM Sep 13 2018  4:07PM
user449     huntgroup1  user91      SHEJJSMM27  Sep 13 2018  4:00PM Sep 13 2018  4:02PM
user128     huntgroup1  user46      USJEHHS45461    Sep 13 2018  4:02PM Sep 13 2018  4:10PM
```

I can achieve this with the below SQL but naturally this won't work because it is dependent on using MIN and MAX(Recipient) so it won't work.

```
 SELECT 
    MIN(Caller) Caller, 
    MIN(Recipient) HuntGroup, 
    MAX(Recipient) Recipient, 
    MIN(CorrelationCode) CorrelationCode, 
    MIN(StartTime) StartTime, 
    MAX(EndTime) EndTime 
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
         1 AS 'NumAnswers', Caller, Recipient, CorrelationCode, StartTime, EndTime
    FROM #phone_calls
) c 
GROUP BY c.CorrelationCode
HAVING SUM(NumAnswers) > 1
```

I have also played around with ;WITH cte but I am not experienced enough to get both values from it

```
;WITH cte AS 
(
  SELECT Caller, Recipient AS 'HuntGroup', Recipient, CorrelationCode, StartTime, EndTime,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CorrelationCode ORDER BY Recipient) rn
  FROM #phone_calls
)

SELECT * FROM cte
WHERE rn = 2
```

So, if there is any TSQL gurus out there that can offer a solution, it would be appreciated.

Comment: what happens to correlation code: `YHJASA434`, you don't include records with 1 row?

Comment: Yes correct, we plan to omit these records as there was no answer on the second leg of the call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good day,

Please check if one of these solutions fit your need (I use table phone_calls instead of #phone_calls):

```
-- Option 1
;with MyCTE as (
    select 
        [Caller], Recipient, CorrelationCode, StartTime, EndTime
        ,RN = ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by [Caller], CorrelationCode order by StartTime, EndTime)
    from phone_calls
)
,MyCTE2 as (
    select RN, [Caller], Recipient as HuntGroup, null as Recipient, CorrelationCode, StartTime, null as EndTime
    from MyCTE
    where RN = 1
    union all
    select RN, [Caller], null as HuntGroup, Recipient, CorrelationCode, null as StartTime, EndTime
    from MyCTE
    where RN = 2
)
select [Caller],MAX(HuntGroup),MAX(Recipient),CorrelationCode,MAX(StartTime),MAX(EndTime)
from MyCTE2
group by [Caller], CorrelationCode
having max(RN) > 1
GO


-- Option 2:
;with MyCTE as (
    select 
        [Caller], Recipient, CorrelationCode, StartTime, EndTime
        ,RN = ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by [Caller], CorrelationCode order by StartTime, EndTime)
    from phone_calls
)
,MyCTE1 as (
    select RN, [Caller], Recipient, CorrelationCode, StartTime, EndTime
    from MyCTE
    where RN = 1
)
,MyCTE2 as (
    select RN, [Caller], Recipient, CorrelationCode, StartTime, EndTime
    from MyCTE
    where RN = 2
)
SELECT 
    t1.Caller, t1.Recipient as HuntGroup, t2.Recipient, t1.CorrelationCode, 
    t1.StartTime, t2.EndTime
from MyCTE1 t1
LEFT JOIN MyCTE2 t2 ON t1.Caller = t2.Caller and t1.CorrelationCode = t2.CorrelationCode
where not t2.Caller IS NULL
```

Comment: Works beautifully! Thanks for taking the time to offer two varying solutions. Will mark as answer.

Comment: You are most welcome @James `;-)`. I am glad I could help a bit